# Android L: LinkageError crashes application

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

As part of testing an existing Android app against the L preview, the app is crashing with the following exception:

```
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126): Process: com.example, PID: 2126
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126): java.lang.LinkageError: com.example.BaseActivity
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:222)
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:215)
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
```

The app works fine in API levels 14-19, but crashes on start up with this cryptic error on the L preview. The compile/targetSdk version is still set to API 19.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was a conflicting method in `BaseActivity`. I had created a helper method called `getDrawable(int drawableId)` that had the same signature as a method added to the `Activity` class in Android L.

This conflict caused the `LinkageError`. To fix the issue, I simply renamed my helper method so it wouldn't conflict with the new built-in method.

Comment: This solved my problem, but I needed to change the Compile Sdk Version to Android 5.0 in Module Settings, before having Android Studio showing this and other errors linked to the change in the targetSdk to API 21

Answer (score -1):

07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126): Process: com.example, PID: 2126
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126): java.lang.LinkageError: com.example.BaseActivity
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:222)
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:215)
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
07-08 10:05:39.024: E/AndroidRuntime(2126):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)

Comment: Please post more than just a stack trace when posting an answer. This above is not an answer at all.